# csv.writer not writing entire output to CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am attempting to scrape the artists' Spotify streaming rankings from Kworb.net into a CSV file and I've nearly succeeded except I'm running into a weird issue.

The code below successfully scrapes all 10,000 of the listed artists into the console:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

URL = "https://kworb.net/spotify/artists.html"
result = requests.get(URL)
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', id="spotifyartistindex")

header_tags = table.find_all('th')
headers = [header.text.strip() for header in header_tags]

rows = []
data_rows = table.find_all('tr')

for row in data_rows:
    value = row.find_all('td')
    beautified_value = [dp.text.strip() for dp in value]
    print(beautified_value)

    if len(beautified_value) == 0:
        continue

    rows.append(beautified_value)
```

The issue arises when I use the following code to save the output to a CSV file:

```
with open('artist_rankings.csv', 'w', newline="") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

For whatever reason, only 738 of the artists are saved to the file. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: Have you examined the output file to see if there's anything it can tell you? How does it end? If you look in the data, is there anything notable about the last written item (or the next one after it, that never does get written)? How are you counting the amount of output in the file? Could the issue be with how you're reading the file, rather than writing it?

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Using your code it saves all 10,000 artists.

Comment: I'm starting to think maybe my computer is timing out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative approach, you might want to make your life easier next time and use `pandas`.

Here's how:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

source = requests.get("https://kworb.net/spotify/artists.html")
df = pd.concat(pd.read_html(source.text, flavor="bs4"))
df.to_csv("artists.csv", index=False)
```

This outputs a `.csv` file with `10,000` artists.

[image]

Comment: Oh wow, this was A LOT simpler and did the trick. I'll look more into Pandas! Thank you so much!